# SQL string lookup. This worked, but seems like it isn't best practice

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, substring

Using SSMS 2014

I have data in the db in a particular column. The average line of data looks something like this:

```
(5:30) 3-J.WINSTON PASS INCOMPLETE DEEP LEFT TO 13-M.EVANS (23-R.ALFORD).
```

My task is to retrieve the first player featured in the line, in this case I am retrieving J.Winston.

I used this to retrieve and update a column with the name. It worked exactly as needed. But something about it tells me this is poorly constructed. Any tips on improving?

```
UPDATE nfl.dbo.Temp_NFL2015
Set Player_Name = SUBSTRING(description,LEN(Left(description,Patindex('%-%',description)))+1,CHARINDEX(' ',description,LEN(Left(description,Patindex('%-%',description))))-1-LEN(Left(description,PATINDEX('%-%', description))))
from NFL.dbo.Temp_NFL2015
```

Comment: One suggestion, which may sound like a cop out to you, would be to clean up that column into several columns of the data you want to query.  Your queries will run very slowly if you have to do so much string manipulation just to get out a name.

Comment: Yes, I did consider that. The text string as a whole can contain 1-* player names in it, so sometimes I might be populating 2 columns for the first row, then 4 columns for the next, then just 1, then 3. Guess I could null out the leftover. Anyways, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normalization of the data would help simplify things when you're extracting data or doing research.

Considering your example:

```
(5:30) 3-J.WINSTON PASS INCOMPLETE DEEP LEFT TO 13-M.EVANS (23-R.ALFORD).
```

The syntax (roughly) works out to:

```
(Game Time) (Source Player) (Action) (Target Player) ((Other Involved Players))
```

This suggests a base table **Actions** with the following structure:

```
ActionID (identity to mark discrete actions)
GameTime
SourcePlayer
Action
TargetPlayer
```

To include other involved players, we split that off into a separate table, **Action_InvolvedPlayers:**

```
InvolvedActionID (referent to Actions.ActionID)
InvolvedPlayer
```

Points for consideration:

- Your dataset likely contains multiple games, so consider an explicit way to say 'this game had this action take place'
- It might make sense to store player data in another table and just referent values in the **Actions** table.

Comment: Wow. That's intense. I'm kind of picking up what you are telling me, but not far along to execute. Thank you for the direction though. Maybe I'll post a separate question when I try to build this out. Thank you for the advice.

Comment: Glad it was helpful! You might take a look at http://www.essentialsql.com/get-ready-to-learn-sql-database-normalization-explained-in-simple-english/ for a little more in-depth look at what normalization usually entails.